# Spawning system in Unity with c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm struggling with spawning system in Unity.

I'm trying to spawn an item only if it is the right time for it and the previous one is already collected, and if it's not, then don't spawn it.

After running the game, my item doesn't appear anywhere on setted spawn points.

Here is a little bit of my code, I don't know why it doesnt't work correctly.

```
public Transform[] spawnPoints;
public GameObject spawnItem;

private float timeBtwSpawn;
public float startTimeBtwSpawn;

private void Start()
{
    timeBtwSpawn = startTimeBtwSpawn;
}

void Update()
{
    int rand = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);

    if (timeBtwSpawn <= 0 && spawnItem == null)
    {
        Instantiate(spawnItem, spawnPoints[rand].position, Quaternion.identity);
        timeBtwSpawn = startTimeBtwSpawn;
    }
    else
    {
        timeBtwSpawn -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you do `if(spawnItem == null)` -> `Instantiate(spawnItem)`

**You can't instantiate something that does not exist**

I guess you would rather want to do something like

```
public Transform[] spawnPoints;

// The prefab you will spawn referenced via the Inspector in Unity
public GameObject spawnItem;

// Reference to the currently existing instance in your scene
private GameObject _lastSpawnedItem;

private float timeBtwSpawn;
public float startTimeBtwSpawn;

private void Start()
{
    timeBtwSpawn = startTimeBtwSpawn;
}

void Update()
{
    if (timeBtwSpawn <= 0 && !_lastSpawnedItem)
    {
        // you can save a bit of work by getting your random only where needed
        var rand = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
        _lastSpawnedItem = Instantiate(spawnItem, spawnPoints[rand].position, Quaternion.identity);
        timeBtwSpawn = startTimeBtwSpawn;
    }
    else
    {
        timeBtwSpawn -= Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

where `spawnItem` is the **PREFAB asset** you are going to spawn while `_lastSpawnedItem` is the actual currently existing **instance** in your Scene.

---

You could also implement the same as a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html) which is often easier to understand and maintain. In your case it is way shorter and doesn't require so many external fields:

```
public Transform[] spawnPoints;
public GameObject spawnItem;
public float startTimeBtwSpawn;

private IEnumerator Start()
{
    GameObject lastSpawnedItem = null;

    // This is ok in an IEnumerator as long as you yield somewhere inside
    while(true)
    {
        // cooldown
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(startTimeBtwSpawn);

        // then additionally wait until last item destroyed
        yield return new WaitWhile(() => _lastSpawnedItem);

        // after both conditions are fulfilled spawn and start again
        var rand = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
        lastSpawnedItem = Instantiate(spawnItem, spawnPoints[rand].position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```